# Cannot find 'Label' in scope - error for Catalyst

Tags: ios14, xcode12

Getting this error for Catalyst:
Cannot find 'Label' in scope - error for Catalyst

My setup: iOS Deployment target: 14.1 Xcode Version 12.1 (12A7403) macOS Big Sur 11.0 Beta (20A5395g)

Anyone had same issue?